# Solving a problem in mathcad using programming

Tags: loops, vector, root, integral, mathcad

I have a problem solver in the first image, it returns the t0 value:

[Problem solver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgS8c.png)

It'd be quite enough, but I need to modify this "code" to use 13 values instead of one t1, as in second image ([Vector of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkpkA.png)). I tried to make it straightforward and paste in this vector, but error appears that only scalar can be used.

Ok, I hope, I made it clear to understand the point :D...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use vectorization symbol from Matrix-palette (or Ctrl+"-")

[image]